# How to use wildcard in file path name for pattern matching in R?

Tags: r, directory, filepath, grepl

I have a directory with my rproj and a "data" folder for all outputs. There are 40 subdirectories within the data folder containing each an "output.csv". The subdirectories have completely different names but all end with 1 or 2.

```
data/****1/output.csv
data/****2/output.csv
```

The astericks represent the varying part of the name (different number of letters), and each csv I need has the exact same name.

I need to seperately list all of the "output.csv"s into based on whether its subdirectory ends with 1 or 2, and I have been trying with the grep() function

```
allOutputFiles <- list.files(pattern = "output.csv", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)

files1 <- grep(pattern = "./data/1$", allOutputFiles, value = TRUE)
files2 <- grep(pattern = "./data/2$", allOutputFiles, value = TRUE)
```

But every time I run it, it returns `character(0)`. If I add a '\' in front of the 1$, it returns `invalid regular expression './data/\1$', reason 'Invalid back reference'`

How do I properly apply wildcard to the varying file path?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dirname` to get the parent directory, then `gsub` to extract the last character of it. Then we use `split` to separate the filenames by this one letter.

```r
# allOutputFiles <- c("data/****1/output.csv","data/****2/output.csv")
allOutputFiles <- list.files(pattern = "output.csv", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
gsub(".*(.)$", "\\1", dirname(allOutputFiles))
# [1] "1" "2"
out <- split(allOutputFiles, gsub(".*(.)$", "\\1", dirname(allOutputFiles)))
out
# $`1`
# [1] "data/****1/output.csv"
# $`2`
# [1] "data/****2/output.csv"
```

If you want to index on that, index with `out[["1"]]` (while `out[[1]]` would conveniently work here, that's coincidence based on your choice of last-letters and should not be relied on).